# Convert the text from a String to a Double

Tags: swift, type-conversion

Im trying to convert a String directly in a Double.

```swift
@IBAction func addMemberButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let member = Member(name: nameTextField.text ?? "", saldo: saldoTextField.text ?? 0.0 , surname: firstnameTextField.text ?? "")
```

But this doesn't work at the "saldo" point. Is it possible to convert it directly to a Double?

Comment: @Ollie I'm at the very beginning of coding so I don't really understand that :c

Comment: For user-entered text you really should be using a `NumberFormatter` to convert between `String` and `Double`.

Comment: @rmaddy okey thank you :D